# Change the color of a table's cell on mouse click using Javascript

Tags: javascript, colors, onclick, cell

How could I assign 3 colors to a cell, and change them on every click? Let's say I have a 10x10 table, and the default colour is white, on the first click on a cell it changes black, on the second it changes to grey, and on the third it's white again, and for every colour the cells also get a value, like:

white: 0
black: 1
grey: 2.

I want to make a puzzle game (Griddler exactly) and every cell must be black and grey if the puzzle is solved correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Here is a working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xm5qp/)

inside `window.onload` (or DOM ready, whichever you'd like):

```
var colors = ["white","black","gray"]//array of colors 
var reverseRef = {"white":0,"black":1,"gray":2}; 

var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("block");//block is a class name you should give your blocks

for(var i=0;i<cells.length;i++){//attach an event to all blocks
    cells[i].onclick = function(){//when you click them
        //change the background color
        //(reverseRef[this.styles.backgroundColor]+1)%3 means get the number value for the color, increase it by one, and modulus it by 3 (which means you only get values between 0 and 2
        this.style.backgroundColor=colors[(reverseRef[this.style.backgroundColor]+1)%3];
    }
}
```

(note, in a browser onclick should be an event listener using `addEventListener` and shimming with `attachEvent` in old IE if you need to support it)